# how to get objects with the same property and has the max value in array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get objects with the same property and has the max value in array 
I have a data like

```
data = [{title: "test1", version: 1},
{title: "test2", version: 3},
{title: "test1", version: 2}, 
{title: "test2", version: 2},
{title: "test2", version: 1}];
```

And I want the result

```
result = [{title: "test1", version: 2},
{title: "test2", version: 3}];
```

Is there any better ways than what I did here?

```
var titles = [...new Set(data.map(o=> o.title))];
var recentVersions = [];
for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
      var recentVersion = null;
      for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
        if(titles[i] === data[j].title){
          if(!recentVersion){
            recentVersion = data[j];
          }else if (recentVersion.version < data[j].version){
            recentVersion = data[j];
          }
        }
      }
      recentVersions.push(recentVersion);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up array methods like map, filter and in this case reduce:

```
let result = data.reduce((r, x)=> {
    if(!r[x.title] || r[x.title].version < x.version)
        r[x.title] = x;
    return r;
}, {});
```

(this is of course an object map, depending on your use-case you need to get the values with a call to `Object.values(result)` or could iterate over the object itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.max` method in combination with `filter` and `map` method.

```js
let data = [{title: "test1", version: 1}, {title: "test2", version: 3}, {title: "test1", version: 2}, {title: "test2", version: 2}, {title: "test2", version: 1}]; 
let uniqueTitles = [...new Set(data.map(a => a.title))];
data = uniqueTitles.map(function(key){
  return { title:key, version : Math.max(...data.filter(a=>a.title == key).map(a=>a.version)) };
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map from your array of unique titles to get the result you expect:

```js
const data = [
    {title: "test1", version: 1},
    {title: "test2", version: 3},
    {title: "test1", version: 2}, 
    {title: "test2", version: 2},
    {title: "test2", version: 1}
];

const titles = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.title))];
const result = titles.map(title => ({
  title,
  version: Math.max(...data.filter(d => d.title === title).map(d => d.version))
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and use a object look up to get highest version number for a given title.

```js
var data = [{title: "test1", version: 1}, {title: "test2", version: 3}, {title: "test1", version: 2}, {title: "test2", version: 2}, {title: "test2", version: 1}],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.title] = r[o.title] || {version: 0};
      if(r[o.title].version < o.version)
        r[o.title] = o;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```